# JavaCompiler and runtime.exec both can't compile a program because they can't find the compiler

Tags: java, compilation

I am trying to make my application compile a .java file. However, I'm running into a notable flaw: apparently, when running through Eclipse (for testing), the system compiler can't be found. I've tried `JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`, but compiler is just null; I've tried running through `runtime.exec()`, testing the command run manually on the command line (and having it work just fine there), but it still returns the "cannot find javac" error that usually means that the path isn't installed correctly. Eclipse will compile the actual program I'm running, but code run IN Eclipse can't find any such compiler. I don't want to manually set the PATH variable, because I'm planning on distributing this program to others, so how else do I fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're running with a JRE, not a JDK. The compiler is only part of the JDK (Java **Development** Kit), and is not part of the JRE (Java Runtime Environment). Eclipse comes with it's own compiler, so it works fine for development with just the JRE.

Comment: You're right. Changing the system library from JRE to JDK worked flawlessly. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, @Andreas commented the answer, and I figured out the rest. In my program's settings, I had the JRE in use by default. I had to change it to the JDK (which came with the JRE installed, as of Java 1.8) to access the compiler; I did this by going into my build path, adding the JDK as the "JRE System Library," and deleting the old library.